# How to center caption with dynamic width button nearby?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a green header section and two objects in it: caption and button. I need to center caption relatively to green section, but it should react on button width growth keeping position as close to center as possible not overlapping each other. 
The whole text should be visible. 
The button can be absent (*ngIf). 
The caption text can be different as well.

You can change html structure. Css/sass only.

See my attempts to solve the issue in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yq35v6c1/)!

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class='title'>
    <span class='title-text'>
      Caption
    </span>
  </h1>

  <button>
    dynamic width
  </button>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the wrapper to

position: relative;
justify-content: center;

and then just position the button absolutely

position: absolute;
right: 10px;

Just change the value of right to your desired result.